# Different Cosine Similarity functions give different results for Word2vec vectors

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I am trying to implement a Cosine Similarity/Distance function similar to `gensim.similarity` function or  `cosine` function (from `scipy.spatial.distance`).
Here is the example:

```
x = model.wv['best']
y = model.wv['amber']
print(cosine(x,y))
```

The result is '1.0', according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy-spatial-distance-cosine) that means that a dot product is 0.

When I use `gensim.similarity` function I get a different result:

```
print(model.wv.similarity('amber','best'))
0.0757624812318
```

From here I can find Distance by subtracting similarity value from 1.
I have tried to implement the Cosine Similarity by myself by writing the code above:

```
 cosine_similarity = np.dot(model.wv['best'], model.wv['amber'])/(np.linalg.norm(model.wv['best'])* np.linalg.norm(model.wv['amber']))
```

output:

```
nan
/Users/art/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:42: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in float_scalars
```

When I do just this:

```
amber = model.wv['amber']
best = model.wv['best']
res= np.dot(amber, best)
```

I get no warning message but `0` as a result.

Any idea whats wrong with my implementation and the `scipy` implementation of similarity?

Comment: This is not reproducable since we don't know what `model.wv['best']` is. Please share an [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: @MaxPowers  I am not sure how to share that, since in word2vec every word is represented by vector of (1,300) dimension.

Comment: This is why should provide a **minimal, verifyable** example as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). That means, post some really short example data that illustrate the problem.